# When the RHEL 7.7 is coming to an end of support and end of life?

Tags: linux, operating-system, rhel7

Can someone advise when the RHEL7.7 is coming to an end of life? So that our application should jump to the next version?

I have this link https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata#Maintenance_Support_2_Phase, but I am confused with a lot of terms like EOS, ELS, Support Phase 1, Phase 2, and SAP support?

any help with links or document is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link is probably clearer to follow:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux

For RHEL 7 phase 1 (full support and updates software and hardware drivers) ended in August 2020

Phase 2 (security patches) are offered until June 2024